# How to get description from CRON expression and viceversa in Hangfire natively?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cron, hangfire

I have implemented Hangfire in an ASP.NET Core 3 application as per defined schedule(s). I am creating schedule(s) (CRON expression) dynamically via different Web API(s).

I couldn't find anything in Hangfire to get the description from CRON expression and also to get CRON expression from description/ interval natively. However, I found two nuget packages:

- **CronExpressionDescriptor** : which gets description from CRON expression.
- **CronEspresso** : which gets CRON expression from description/ interval.

I have implemented both and it is working as expected.

---

My code sample:

---

```
using CronExpressionDescriptor;
using CronEspresso.NETCore;

...

string cronExpression = "* 5 * * * *";            //every 5 minutes
var cronDescription = ExpressionDescriptor.GetDescription(cronExpression);
string cronExpressionAgain = CronGenerator.GenerateMinutesCronExpression(5);
```

---

I came to know Hangfire utilizes **NCrontab**. So, is there any way to achieve above functionalities natively to remove external dependency?

Share your thoughts.